# How to add a a row on a multi index data frame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Ok, so I'm struggling with the following, let's say I have the following table

[image]

What I want to do is that on each territorial column I could add a column with the sum per index of territorial, what I want that I could look like this:

[image]

It's basically this, to add the rows of totals per index.

Comment: Please include your data as text not image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['EFFECTIVIDAD'] = df['Turno'].div(df['Folio Cita']).mul(100)
df['TERRITORIAL'] = df['TERRITORIAL'].ffill()
df_sum = df.groupby(['TERRITORIAL']).agg({'Folio Cita':'sum', 'Turno':'sum'}).reset_index()
df_sum['EFFECTIVIDAD'] = df_sum['Turno'].div(df_sum['Folio Cita']).mul(100)
df_sum['REGIONAL'] = 'Total ' + df_sum['TERRITORIAL']

df = pd.concat([df, df_sum], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by=['TERRITORIAL'])
print(df)
```